# Using correct pip version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip

I'm encountering an issue while setting up a new project in Python 3.11. Here's the sequence of steps I've taken:

Upgraded from Python 3.10 to 3.11.
Created a new virtual environment for the project.
Attempted to install dependencies via a requirements.txt file.
Specifically required ipykernel for running Jupyter notebooks.
When attempting to run a cell within the Jupyter notebook, I receive the following error:

```
Running cells with 'llm-detoxification-venv' requires the ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment. 
Command: 'c:/my_path/llm-detoxification-venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall'
```

After running the suggested command, the problem persists. It seems to be trying to uninstall packages outside the virtual environment, which makes me suspect an issue with the pip version or environment configuration.

What I've tried:

Running the suggested command to install ipykernel.
Ensuring that my virtual environment is activated before installing packages.
Checking the version of pip within the virtual environment to confirm it corresponds with Python 3.11.
Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to run cells in my notebook.

Question:

How can I correctly install ipykernel in my Python 3.11 virtual environment and ensure that Jupyter notebook can run cells using this environment?

Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: Please run the `pip list` command after activating the virtual environment and share the output.

Comment: The output is really long and it has ipykernel with version 6.26.0. However, I believe that this is showing the global pip list. Because I am still getting the error. Do you want to see the whole long output?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your vscode terminal after running the command to install ipykernel and statusbar should also be in the screenshot.

Comment: The problem is solved, I've been set the PYTHONPATH as my global python path, that's why it was forcing to look at that path and gave me those errors.